# VS 2022 No longer allows me to drag and drop links to css/js files

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, drag-and-drop, visual-studio-2022

In VS 2019, You're able to drag a JS or CSS file and it'll automatically create the src link to that file. In 2022 this functionality is no longer there, When looking for solutions I only saw two possibilities:

1. Make sure Drag and Drop Text Editing is enabled (It is, not the fix)
2. Disable LSP in Preview features in the environment section (Can't even see this option, even on latest version)

Any help would be appreciated as this does limit how fast we are able to complete our work.

Comment: Drag & Drop is not supported yet for the LSP editors.  We're starting development on the feature this sprint, hoping to get it implemented in the 17.2 timeframe.  The opt-out for the Razor LSP editor is now located under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Advanced -> Use legacy Razor Editor for ASP.NET Core

Comment: @Jimmy This worked, thanks!

Comment: For vs2022 this should be fixed in: Visual Studio 2022 version 17.3 Preview 3([click to go on to download page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/)). Accordingly with quote from "Fixed - Pending Release" [developer community issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-drag-javascript-or-css-files-onto-an-html-pag/1526177) from Jul 13, 2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use them.

There is a work around suggested by Microsoft: Tools-->Options-->Text Editor-->HTML-->Advanced-->Use Legacy Razor Editor for Asp.NET (Yes) -->OK

And restart the visual studio.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).